# Not expected values ​in onValuesChange method

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using Form.List inside Form.List and when removing the inner formList onValuesChange() is giving away an unexpected second argument.
form.getFieldsValue() returns the same. But if you call the onFinish() method, then it is correct the value I expected.

demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-izdsz3-ubydjz?file=index.js.

How to reproduce:

1. Open console.
2. Click button "Add field"
3. Clcik button "Add nickname"
4. Delete field
5. Click button "Submit"
6. Check the differences

[differences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvaXh.png)
[reproduction gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62Mbh.gif)

Comment: it's bug https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/28185.  Still not fixed  ..